# Copy system settings from one PC to another

Tags: kde, backup, system-settings

I have installed and customized my KDE desktop in one of my laptop. Now I have another laptop where I also installed KDE. Since I have already did the customization in one laptop already, I want to copy the system settings from there to the newly installed desktop so that I don't have to do the customizations again.

Is there any way I can copy the system settings from one laptop to another?

Answer (score 1):

There is no full automatic approach.

- If the Ubuntu versions and KDE desktop versions are identical, you can copy over the hidden user configuration files in your home folder from one computer to the other.
- Then, you still will need to install any missing programs and/or themes that were installed system wide on the other system.